# Harmattan: How to listen for incoming sms event

Tags: meego-harmattan

Is there any example for Meego Harmattan that I can look at so that I can develop an app that is aware of incoming sms/mms/email event? I looked through the Developer Libraries, API Topics, API Libraries but couldn't find any explicit examples/documentations that say how to do it.

Any input would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The QtMobility Messaging API documentation provides examples on how to listen to messaging events. See http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/messaging.html (in the end there are two examples)